# Is Dark Matter an unnecessary hypothesis with an geocentric model?

Tags: cosmology

Would it be possible to eliminate the need for Dark Matter as a hypothesis with a geocentric universe?

The reason I ask is because I have never seen the geocentric model put to the test with modern day theories of gravity/relativity. I am curious if this has ever been done, simply as an ode to the olden days when everyone used to think the Earth was in the center.

Comment: The Sun is not the center of the universe either, so what would change?

Comment: Im not sure how to quote, by posting here am i responding directly to fgsuz?

Comment: Yes, I'm watching this. But you could also comment about other topics, like clarifying aspects of your question. If you want to quote, add the symbol @ before the username. If you cant to add more information, add more comments or edit your question if it's too long. Try not to create a huge list of comments.

Comment: The reason i made this topic is i assume the physics would change slightly if the universe had an absolute center, something that the copernican principle does not predict. The thing that has always gotten me tho is how close relativity is to geocentrism, its almost like they are one in the same and i was curious if our current tests for our current theories have ever been done but with a presumption the universe had an absolute center of mass, and how that would change things.

Comment: I really don't see how relativity is close to geocentrism.

Comment: Well to word it a different way, our current view of the cosmos inherently allows a earth centric point of view on the physics side of things (but you would need to ignore observational data of course). I am not suggesting anything here at all, i was merely curious if anything would change in regards to dark matter if we had a presumption the universe had a center. For example, would it be possible that local gravity is different than what we observe in far reaching clusters?

Comment: Your question doesn't even make any sense. The notion of a center is defined for finite regions, and even then the center doesn't necessarily lie in the region (for non-convex regions). What do you even mean when you say center in relation to the universe? Also I don't see what this has to do with gravity or dark matter. Are you saying that everything else should orbit the earth? Because that wouldn't be possible gravitationally.

Comment: Why is the notion of a center defined for finite regions? Also lets remove earth for a second and just focus on the center part, i just brought up geocentrism as that is the most widely known idea of a center. I am simply curious if calculations have been done with modern day theorems and how/if that would affect the need for dark matter/energy.

Comment: Already Aristarchos of Samos (c. 310 - c. 230 before counting) knew that a geocentric model made no sense. So why start this discussion all over after 2000 years?

Comment: Im just trying to look at the dark matter problem in a different way my2cts. I dont believe there are multiple universe nor do i believe there is invisible matter that interacts with the matter we can see. I am simply curious if the tests we are doing now for dark matter have been simulated in a mass centric universe like geocentrism.

Comment: @user200200 The Q & A sections of Stack Exchange are not a **forum**; a place where you throw out random thoughts and then have people discuss them. That is what you use the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=physics.stackexchange.com) for. Now granted you do not have chat privileges yet, that comes with 20 points of reputation. But getting 20 points is fairly easy, so I would suggest you aim for that, and then post this question in the chat. Welcome to Physics SE! :-)

Comment: @user200200 The reason you are getting downvotes is very easy to suss: first — as I just said — bouncing ideas around for discussion is not suitable for the Q & A section. Second: the question itself is kind of... flimsy. Basically it says: Ok, if we — just for laughs — postulate that the geocentric model **is** accurate... can we then also assume we can just ignore the issues that led us to hypothesise about dark matter? There is no way to answer that because you have just taken known physics and thrown that out the window. How could we form an answer from that?!

Comment: The point is that the notion of a centre *isn't* defined for infinite regions.

Comment: It may be interesting to note that the LTB models (in my mind) are as close as we get to a "geocentric model" in modern formalism, in that they assume that we as observers have a privileged position, while successfully producing the correct angular-diameter–distance–redshift relationship ($d_A(z)$) without the need of dark *energy* (not dark matter). One factor distinguishing the two models is the cosmic age, which can be constrained by metal deficient stars, but last I read  both $\Lambda$CDM and the corresponding LTB model  fall withing one standard deviation from observational constraints.

Answer (score 1):

A geocentric model is incompatible with basic Newtonian gravity, because of what we know about the masses of celestial bodies (the Earth is too small). So there is no "geocentric model" which makes sense gravitationally, with or without dark matter.

Answer (score 0):

A geocentric universe that yet had the same observational characteristics would be utterly different from how we think our universe works. So different that your question almost becomes meaningless.

Consider parallax: we can observe that stars move slightly relative to further background stars on a yearly cycle because of Earth's orbit around the sun. This is a very well measured effect. In a geocentric universe there needs to be some physical effects that move stars or light annually to fit observations: this would be entirely new physics that changes well understood rules for gravity and light (plus models of how stars and galaxies work) to something entirely different.

One can certainly entertain oneself with coming up with such a physics, but it would be rather contrived and it would need to throw out a lot of fundamental concepts. At this point one can of course just throw out dark matter too, since one is making up entirely new versions of gravity and why we are observing what we are observing.

Now, if we imagine that Tycho Brahe was a super-astronomer and back in the 16th century documented what we can currently document, he would no doubt have a hard time keeping a geocentric view. He would observe that all exoplanets are orbiting their stars, he would measure heliocentric cometary orbits, he would measure the parallaxes of stars. Maybe he could argue that God made Earth the true centre the Sun orbits around and then everything else moves exactly as if the sun was the origin, but it would look even more contrived than his [actual Tychonian system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonic_system) - especially since he would have measurements of small bodies following gravity-affected trajectories past heavier bodies.

He might have explained away the rotation curves of galaxies by saying the stars are affixed to crystal disks or something, but would likely soon be troubled by galactic mergers. The real trouble would start when Kepler began doing n-body simulations on the Uranienborg supercomputer to try to get the galaxy formation going and noticed that (1) some kind of gravitational law is needed rather than crystal planes and spheres - which incidentally explains solar systems much better, (2) there has to be extra mass to get this to work on a galactic scale.

Comment: Apparently i didnt understand the observances played such a huge role in this subject (as i asked people to suspend disbelief on planetary observances from years past here). I am simply hung up on the idea that there COULD be a center in our current understanding of the universe, denoted by general relativity. Obviously i am no expert here but is it not possible the physics of a mass centric universe could change ever so slightly to where the need for dark matter disappears? What about a mass centric universe does not fit into relativity or newtons laws?

Comment: Why do i have two downvotes for my first topic ever on this forum lol? Is it frowned upon to question our current understanding of the universe when the alternatives are multiverses and invisible matter? Obviously we have something wrong right now, why would discussing alternative theories be frowned upon?

Comment: @user200200 Proposing geocentrism means that your theory is inconsistent with _thousands_ of experiments stretching back for _centuries_. It feels like you just picked the most "heretical" idea you could think of and went for it.

Comment: @user200200 It's about as valuable as proposing that all cosmological problems are solved by postulating that stars are made of cheese. It's not clear how this would actually solve any problems, while it would make the things we do know stop working.

Comment: Obviously i need some explanations, if you would. What about a mass centric universe would not fit into our current understanding of the universe? I only used the word geocentrism as thats the only model i knew was widely accepted for a period of time, feel free to envision any point in the cosmos as your center.

Comment: @user200200 Well, don't think about dark matter yet, focus on the smallest problem first. How do you explain the orbits of the planets in your geocentric model, without throwing away basically all physics ever? Why do the planets and Sun move around in epicycles, erratically switching direction?

Comment: @user200200 After that, how do you explain the fact that in every _other_ astronomical system we observe, the small things orbit around the big things? Why is that pattern broken for Earth alone? I could go on, but you have the work of a lifetime ahead of you to make your theory consistent with even what we knew in the 1800s, let alone everything since.

Comment: Have you read any of the things ive posted lol? Ive specifically asked people to suspend disbelief about orbits for the sake of this discussion. Are you insinuating telescope readings from ~400 years ago trump modern day discoveries like the cosmic microwave background readings or general relativity in itself? I just need to know how the physics work if we did todays testing from a basis of assumption that there was a center of mass in the universe.

Comment: @user200200 If you're explicitly saying you _can't_ explain even the most basic thing about our solar system, what makes you think you can explain much more complicated things about our universe? The way the physics would work is that it doesn't. It's on you to show otherwise.

Comment: What you are saying is 'assume all the physics we know is completely wrong and now come up with completely different physics'?  That is off-topic for this forum on at least the grounds of 'not mainstream physics', 'too broad' and 'primarily opinion based'.